# c# maui android app crashing in release mode

Tags: c#, android, maui

Basically I'm quite experienced with c# in general and with desktop / asp.net apps but I am new to mobile programming and to MAUI. Also either I'm really bad at searching lately or the internet is really poor and messy when it comes to knowledge about how to publish you MAUI apps and handle them afterwards.

So I decided to ask here about the current problem I can't break through. The problem is, while my app works on the Android emulator and on the physical device when I run it in debug via Visual Studio, when I publish it and run it in release mode, installed from the .apk file on that same mentioned physical device, it crashes.

I have a logging system in my app so I was hoping I'll learn something from logs, but there's no error there. Just a few information logs about some initial operations the app does and then poof - it just dies. I have no idea why, what's the cause, where exactly in the code an error occurs, nothing. So my question is - how do I even begin to examine this problem? How to debug it? What should be my next step? Does the Android have some kind of Event Viewer like Windows does maybe?

@EDIT 30.1.24
I checked my phone's logs (using Device Log function in Visual Studio, which I had no idea about when I was writing my post). Seems like the problem I had was related to this piece of code:

```
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState Name="Normal" >
                <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState Name="Selected">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Key=PrimaryDark}" />
                  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateGroupList>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

It's the current code, earlier I didn't have the

```
<VisualStateGroupList></VisualStateGroupList>
```

part and because of that I was getting an exception "InvalidOperationException: VisualStateGroup Names must be unique at build time". So anyway, that particular problem is solved and I am one little yet important piece od information smarter.

Thank you a lot for your answers, I appreciate them very much. I'll also definitely look into crashlytics app center too.

Comment: Have you checked Android logcat for error messages? Also if the app is crashing several times Android usually shows a dialog for creating a crash report.

Comment: Try to use some external cloud base crashlytics nugget for your App to get report of crashes. You can use `crashlytics app center` for it, its simple to use & integrate

Comment: I suppose that you delete the debug app before installing the release app, right?

Comment: Is your logging system also handling crashes? Because there are cloud services with mobile SDKs that do that

Comment: You can use [Diagnostics of App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/) to monitor the problem for your app, which is a cloud service that helps developers monitor the health of an application, delivering the data needed to understand what happens when an app fails during testing or in the wild.